Text Recognition using Tesseract in unity ar without vuforia
How can I perform OCR using Tesseract in AR Unity? I'm new to Unity and don't have much knowledge in this area. I want to write something in my notes, scan it with an AR camera, detect the text, and then place a 3D object above the detected text. How can I achieve this?
